# Stop NSTimer from another view?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I want to stop an NSTimer in `UIRequiredPassowrdViewController` from another view `SettingsTabelViewController`, so I first create the countdown:

```
class UIRequiredPassowrdViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var timer: NSTimer?
    var remainingSeconds = 1000

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "updateTimer:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func updateTimer(timer: NSTimer) {
        remainingSeconds -= 1
        println(remainingSeconds)
    }

    func StopTimerNotication(){
        println("Function Start!")
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
}
```

Then I call function `StopTimerNotication()` from another view `SettingsTabelViewController` :

```
@IBAction func myButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("Button Clicked")
    var myClass: UIRequiredPassowrdViewController=UIRequiredPassowrdViewController()
    myClass.StopTimerNotication()
}
```

And I run the app, the log shows correctly countdown, button clicked and run the function, but the timer just don't get stop:

```
999
998
997
996
995
994
993
992
991
990
989
Button Clicked
Function Start!
988
987
986
985
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`myClass` is a newly initialised view controller, it is totally different with the view controller in which you started the timer. So to solve your problem, basically you need to find a way to tell that specific view controller to stop its timer.
There are two common solutions for such case:
(1) Use notification: In your `UIRequiredPassowrdViewController` register to a specific notification, let's call it `StopTimerNotification`, when you receive such notification stop the timer. And in  `SettingsTabelViewController`, send out `StopTimerNotification` in `myButtonClicked`.
(2) Use delegate: you need a simple protocol here, let's call it `StopTimerProtocol` which will probably have only on method `func stopTimer()`. And your `UIRequiredPassowrdViewController` needs to conform to this protocol and implement that method. Then add a `delegate` property which is a type of `id<StopTimerProtocol>` to `SettingsTabelViewController`. After that, when you present or push `SettingsTabelViewController` on top of `UIRequiredPassowrdViewController` set the `delegate` property. At last, in `SettingsTabelViewController` when `myButtonClicked` just call `self.delegate.stopTimer()`

Answer (score 4):

Declare `NSTimer` as global in AppDelegate.

```
var timer: NSTimer?
```

in your `UIRequiredPassowrdViewController` class

```
class UIRequiredPassowrdViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var remainingSeconds = 1000

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)

        appDelegate.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "updateTimer:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func updateTimer(timer: NSTimer) {
        remainingSeconds -= 1
        println(remainingSeconds)
    }
}
```

in `SettingsTabelViewController` have button in which you want to stop as below.

```
@IBAction func myButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

  let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
  appDelegate.timer?.invalidate()   

}
```

Comment: Great! It's working, so we need a global value to do it, thanks! :)

Comment: Making the timer global is unnecessary. Instead of making the timer visible to every object, just keep around the proper instance of `UIRequiredPassowrdViewController`.

Comment: No. I would argue that it breaks the encapsulation of `UIRequiredPassowrdViewController`.

Comment: A better way to do it is using `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: Although adding the timer to appDelegate solves the problem. I do not agree with this answer at all. You should not use appDelegate to store some global value. We should keep appDelegate as clean as possible, it should only take care of the application life cycle.

Comment: @EricQian give me a good reason why global variables shouldn't be stored on appdelegate. Kirit way is perfect legal, fine and works.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what kirit said except code is in Objective-C for anyone in future who may stumble onto this post

```
//  AppDelegate.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *soundTimer;

//  ViewController.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"

//start timer - call it from anywhere in your ViewController
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.soundTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(playButtonSound1) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

//stop timer - call it from anywhere in your ViewController
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.soundTimer invalidate];
    appDelegate.soundTimer = nil;
```